# For a standard two-dimensional Gaussian vector, find $ \mathbb{P}=\{1\leq\left \| \vec{\xi} \right \|\leq 2\} $

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

For a standard two-dimensional Gaussian vector $ \vec{\xi}=\binom{\xi_{1}}{\xi_{2}} $, find
$ \mathbb{P}=\{1\leq\left \| \vec{\xi} \right \|\leq 2\} $

I am struggling with this exercise and don't know which way I should solve this. Could somebody help, please?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Possibly hint: the norm follows a chi-square distribution.